# Pull info from private site that requires login (Golang)

Tags: http, go, authentication, web-scraping

I am trying to pull my classes from my online timetable, however, it seems as if I cannot get past the login stage. My code is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strings"

    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

type App struct {
    Client *http.Client
}

type Timetable struct {
    Name string
}

const (
    baseURL string = "https://myclasswebsite.com"
)

func (app *App) login() {
    //login := loginInfo()
    client := app.Client
    loginURL := baseURL + "/portal2/#!/login"

    data := url.Values{
        "inputEmail": {"my_actual_username"},
        "password":   {"my_actual_password"},
    }

    response, err := client.PostForm(loginURL, data)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    defer response.Body.Close()

    _, err = ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func (app *App) getTimetable() []Timetable {
    timetableURL := baseURL + "/portal/dashboard"
    client := app.Client

    response, err := client.Get(timetableURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Error fetching response. ", err)
    }

    defer response.Body.Close()

    document, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(response.Body)

    fmt.Println(document.Html())

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading HTTP response body. ", err)
    }

    var classes []Timetable

    document.Find(".timetable table").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        className := strings.TrimSpace(s.Text())
        class := Timetable{
            Name: className,
        }

        classes = append(classes, class)
    })

    return classes
}
```

I changed the base URL and login info just for privacy reasons, however, the rest of the code is as-is.

My main. go file is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cookiejar"
)

func main() {
    jar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)

    app := App{
        Client: &http.Client{Jar: jar},
    }

    app.login()
    classes := app.getTimetable()
    fmt.Println("class array is", classes)
    for index, class := range classes {
        fmt.Printf("%d: %s\n", index+1, class.Name)
    }
}
```

The final print returns an empty slice, and when I print the response.Html() to the console, I receive the login-page Html rather than the dashboard-page HTML.

I'm in no way expecting anyone to fix this for me but a second pair of eyes and maybe a clue in which direction I should go would be helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm unfamiliar with your class website, some ideas for progressing:

You're not checking the status code from your login call.  You may be getting a non-200 status code.

After you've confirmed the status code, check the cookie jar to ensure that a cookie has been saved.  This is probably on the unlikelier side, but it's worth checking.

Lastly, attempt the same sequence with curl with -v (if you haven't already).  That will give you more insight as to what is happening with your call plan.

Comment: Hi, I completely forgot to close this question, so sorry! My issue ended up being with the cookie jar, I completely missed something. I fixed it up around 3 hours after posting this because I realised the dumb error I made. Thank you very much for your input, however, I'll close the question now :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ignoring some cookies accidentally while testing. Whoops...